# MinHeapify printing incorrect value

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, heap

I am trying to visualize why my `minHeapify` is isn't sorting correctly. Here is my code:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Heap {
    
    public void insert2(List<Integer> heap, int value) {
        if(heap.isEmpty()) {
            heap.add(value);
        }
        else {
            heap.add(value);
            for(int index = heap.size() / 2 - 1;index >= 0;index--) {
                minHeapify(heap, index);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void minHeapify(List<Integer> heap, int index) {
        int smallest = index;
        int leftChildIndex = 2 * index + 1;
        int rightChildIndex = 2 * index + 2;
        
        if(leftChildIndex < heap.size() && heap.get(leftChildIndex) < heap.get(smallest)) {
            smallest = leftChildIndex;
        }
        if(rightChildIndex < heap.size() && heap.get(rightChildIndex) < heap.get(smallest)) {
            smallest = rightChildIndex;
        }
        if(smallest != index) {
            int temp  = heap.get(smallest);
            heap.set(smallest, heap.get(index));
            heap.set(index, temp);
            minHeapify(heap, smallest);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> input2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        Heap heap2 = new Heap();
        heap2.insert2(input2, 3);
        heap2.insert2(input2, 4);
        heap2.insert2(input2, 48);
        heap2.insert2(input2, 9);
        heap2.insert2(input2, 5);
        heap2.insert2(input2, 2);
        
        System.out.println(input2);
    }

}
```

The output is `[2, 4, 3, 9, 5, 48]`

The output for min heap should always be sorted. Am I correct with this assumption and should it be `[2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 48]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is correct, and the result after your following insert steps is truely `[2, 4, 3, 9, 5, 48]`.

> The output for min heap should be always sorted

But you are getting a little wrong idea about `MinHeap`, which is every node is smaller than it left and right children node. BUT the right child node can be greater, smaller than it sibling as long as greater than its parent.

So the represented `List` of your heap can't be sort in correct order.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-data-structure/